# I have tried this question multiple times but can't get to find a correct answer from roman iii but i wouldn't mind if one could help me from roman 1

Tags: probability-distributions

1. Let X and Y have the joint p.d.f given by

$f(x,y)= 1,0<x<1 {\rm and}\ 0<y<1$.
otherwise $0$

Compute the following probabilities:

i. $P(X < 1/2, Y < 1/2)$

ii. $P(X + Y < 1)$

iii. $P(X + Y > 1)$

iv. $P(X > 2Y)$

v. $P(X > 1/3)$

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that describes the mathematical issue at hand.

Comment: Notice that since $f(x,y)=1$ on the unit square, $P = \iint f(x,y)\, dx\, dy$ is just the area of the region of integration in the unit square. So all of these can be answered with simple geometry area rules, once you have a good description or sketch of the region.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, please solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your answers... just look at the shaded regions:

[image]